# What is the maths formula to determine the size/weight of a pot/anchor that will hold posts for a sunshade under tension?

Tags: concrete, post

I want to erect a non-permanent sunshade in my yard. Instead of anchoring it into the building or digging holes (this is a rental) I was going to use large plant pots, with a post in them. I could use SOME concrete or weights in there, but the rest should be usable soil.

I plan to remove the shade during extreme weather obviously.

The posts would be 8 to 10 feet off the ground. Some of the sails I've seen ask that you tensions them at something like 300-500N (~70-110 lbf).

If this just seems unfeasible I can always just find something to act as braces between the posts at the top, but if I can avoid that, it would be nice.

Comment: Any container that takes less than four or more muscle men/women to pick up is probably too small.

Comment: Your problem is that they are a PITA to put up and take down just for the times you want to use them.  One time you will leave them up and will not get home soon enough or just forget they are up.  It happens to the best of us.  Ask a sailor what happens when sails are left up.

Comment: Anecdote: 10x10 sunshade, with 30 pounds of concrete on each of 4 corners got picked up and flung about 50 feet into the next yard. Don’t underestimate wind!

Comment: Pots just won't work, I don't know if even the size suggested by @crip659 would work.  Unless the base of the pot was on the order of 5+ feet in diameter.  An option may be to  use your pots and posts, but also use guywires staked into the ground to support the posts laterally.